# Flutter TabView only refreshes on Tab, but not on Swipe

Tags: flutter, view, controller, tabs, swipe

I'm trying to improve my app with the following challenge : I want to populate my Tab View with initially empty TabPages(Widgets) and do the complex stuff (e.g. like database actions) in the TabViews when the Tab is clicked or the Tab is swiped on it.
I finished my programming now but the view is only refreshed when I tab on the TabHeader, but not if I swipe from one page to another. In debugger I see that the widget is replaced by the correct one but it is not displayed. It remains on the old widget.

I have written a little app which shows the problem. It has 5 Tabs, initially filled with MyDefaultWidget, and replaced with MySpecialWidget if selected. Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Tab Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  List<Tab> myTabHeaders = [];
  List<Widget> myTabPages = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 5, vsync: this);
    _tabController.addListener(myTabControllerListener);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      myTabHeaders.add(Tab(text: '$i'));
      myTabPages.add(const MyDefaultWidget());
    }
  }

  void myTabControllerListener() {
    if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
      int newIndex = _tabController.index;
      setState(() {
        myTabPages[newIndex] = const MySpecialWidget();
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorColor: Colors.orange,
          labelColor: Colors.orange,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
          tabs: myTabHeaders,
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: myTabPages,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDefaultWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDefaultWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('DEFAULT'),
    );
  }
}

class MySpecialWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySpecialWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('SPECIAL'),
    );
  }
}
```

If tapping MySpecialWidget is shown. If swiping MyDefaultWidget is shown.

Is there anything I have forgotten to configure ? I'm a little bit confused about the inconsistence. Thanks a lot in advance for some help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dhafin Rayhan's answer describes, the `indexIsChanging` property is only used for the animation itself. Removing it has the effect that your listener function can't tell if the index has changed at all. To fix this you should keep track of the `_tabController.index` by storing it in a variable and refresh your tab's content when it changed. The below code is tested and working.

I also replaced the static colors and changed up the way you store and initialize your tabs. Decide for yourself if you would like to adapt it, but personally, I prefer it this way as I think it's a bit cleaner and simpler to read.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My Tab Demo',
      theme: ThemeData.from(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final TabController _tabController = TabController(length: tabs.length, vsync: this);

  late final Map<Tab, Widget> tabs = {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) Tab(text: '$i'): const MyDefaultWidget(),
  };

  int? tabIndex;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController.addListener(tabBarListener);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  void tabBarListener() {
    if (tabIndex != _tabController.index) {
      tabIndex = _tabController.index;
      setState(() => tabs[tabs.keys.elementAt(tabIndex!)] = const MySpecialWidget());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        title: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          // I advice you to customize the TabBarTheme instead of providing these one-off values
          indicatorColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          labelColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black54,
          tabs: tabs.keys.toList(),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: tabs.values.toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyDefaultWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyDefaultWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('DEFAULT'),
    );
  }
}

class MySpecialWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySpecialWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Center(
      child: Text('SPECIAL'),
    );
  }
}
```

**WARNING:** The tab is only refreshed, when the drag animation is fully completed! This could be perceived as lag. If you would like to already refresh the tabs content when a user half-swipes a tab, use the `offset` property of `TabController` and check if it passes either `-0.5` or `0.5`.

Feel free to reach out if you need any more help :)

Comment: Hi, I did not know so far that swiping is only an animation for the controller without any functional meaning concerning its index. Your solution works fine as intented, thank you very much

Comment: No worries, I'm glad I could help :)  
Swiping actually changes the TabController's index but only after the swipe is completed. However, it doesn't affect `indexIsChanging` and only sets a new value for the `index` integer once the tab is fully switched, so you had to check for yourself if it changed. 
Don't worry tho, I was just trying to explain, the solution is complete and is fully working :)

Comment: One note : I think super call of initState should be at first line  :-)

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed the behavior of the `indexIsChanging` property. From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TabController/indexIsChanging.html):

> This value is true during the animateTo animation that's triggered when the user taps a TabBar tab. It is false when offset is changing as a consequence of the user dragging (and "flinging") the TabBarView.

So if you want your listener to also react to changes caused by swiping the widget, remove the `indexIsChanging` check.

Comment: It's right that this flag is true if tapped and not if swiped. But it wasnt part of my main app. I removed it from test and swiped from tab 0 to tab 1 : That's in the debugger now :

[Debugger of listener][1]

You see that list is updated for tab[1]. But if I resume the debugger, Default Widget is still shown in tab index 1 :


[App after resuming debugger][2]

It is NOT a problem of the controller. The view is not refreshed although setState is called and myTabPages is part of the build tree.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU6hu.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipjVJ.png

Comment: I invite you to copy the code from above (remove the line with indexIsChanging) and start the test app. This might show clearly what I mean